# association relationship in UML

Tags: associations, structure, relationship, uml

As i read through software engineering appendix 1 from Roger Pressman book that

> an association between two classes means that there is a structural
>   relationship between them

what structural relationship means?

Comment: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/rsmhelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xtools.modeler.doc/topics/caggreg.html

Comment: hi @Rohit but i still don't know what exactly a structural relationship means?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

UML differentiates 'structural' and 'behavioural' models.  Class Diagrams, Package Diagrams and a few other capture the structural aspects.  State/Sequence/Activity Diagrams capture behavioural aspects.

'Structural' means it holds over time.  For example, the association between Order and OrderLines ("Order consists of 1 or more OrderLines / OrderLine is part of exactly one Order").  Or Dog and Person ("Dog is owned by exactly one Person / Person owns many Dogs").  Used well, Associations capture invariant rules from the problem domain.  To use the Dog example: the association says a Dog can't ever be owned by more than one Person at any given time.  Doesn't matter if the Dog is running, sitting, or eating: it must have exactly one Owner.  Note also the owner could change over time: but there can never be more than one at any point.

An alternative is to think of Associations as the kind of thing that might be captured using foreign keys in a relational database.

hth.

Comment: I wonder if there is example explain the following:  "An alternative is to think of Associations as the kind of thing that might be captured using foreign keys in a relational database" ?

Comment: Because I think that the association in UML is not easy to understood (at least for me)
Could you please advise me about association in UML(reference or anything else)?
I asked you because I have noticed your amazing answers about UML
thank you

Comment: @Andrew: what is it about Associations that you find difficult/confusing?  If you can be a bit more specific I can give more appropriate answers/pointers.  Thanks for the kind comment btw.

Comment: thank you dude:)
When I model a system,two things I should consider :
 1)not only must I identify the things that form the vocabulary of my system

2)I must also model how these things stand in relation to one another

Comment: My real problem with association relationship:

#I would like to understand the semantic of association in general and specifically the semantic of property that resides on each side of association (association end)

#what is the corresponding of association relationship in programming level?
I really can't figure it out

Comment: @Andrew: I've blogged a couple of times about relationships (http://www.roperia.com/article/345/relationships-are-more-fun and http://www.roperia.com/article/346/relationships-are-more-fun-ii).  These might help with your points re. semantics.  As for translating to programming languages: there is no popular language with 1st class support for relationships.  They are usually decomposed into a pair of pointers (or collections of pointers).  Can I suggest you read the posts - if you still want more post a question here and I'll try to answer (more scope for a full rsp than comments here). hth.

Comment: I am very glad to hear your advice @sfinnie, I'll follow it that's very kind of you